# How to call onStartCommand multiple times in a test?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-service-binding

i have the following design:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
  protected Logger _log;
  int _counter;

  onStartCommand(...){
     _log.print (++_counter);
  }
}

public class MyServiceTestWrapper extends MyService{
  public void setLog(Logger mockLogger){ _logger = mockLogger; }
}

public class MyServiceTest extends ServiceTestClass<MyServiceTestWrapper>{
  public void test_myTest(){
    Logger fakeLogger = Mockito.Mock(Logger.class);

    // HERE IM NOT SURE HOW TO CONTINUE...
    //... 
    //...

    Mockito.verify(fakeLogger.write(Mockito.any(String.class))).times(3);
  }
}
```

how do i get the service instance and make 3 calls to onStartCommand?

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call startService (even if it is already running), `onStartCommand` will be called.

So, to call it 3 times, you can simply write:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MySerivce.class);
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

*Source: Android docs (as shown below)*

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand())

Comment: First of all - thanks. 

But when i'm trying to debug my test i see that in the first time, onStartCommand is called, but in the next time it does not. (even though a call to context.startService(publishIntent); is being performed (for the second time).

any idea?

thanks